# how to send array as function argument from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to pass an array as a function argument from php to js.i am getting the values from
database.

```
while ($rows = pg_fetch_array($qry))
        {
            ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $rows['relation_name_local']?>">
            <?php echo $rows['relation_name_local']?>
            </option>
            <?php
            $app_relation_array[] =  $rows['relation_name_local'];
        }?>
```

i want to pass $app_relation_array[] values through addNewRow() this function
Can anyone please help me with this.
 Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20783991/1607528

Answer (score 2):

**Use json_encode() function and echo it in javascript**

```
    while ($rows = pg_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        ?>
        <option  value="<?php echo $rows['relation_name_local']?>">
        <?php echo $rows['relation_name_local']?>
        </option>
        <?php
        $app_relation_array[] =  $rows['relation_name_local'];
        $new_data = json_encode($app_relation_array[]);
    }?>
```

**And in your html inside script tag**

```
     <script>
        var data = JSON.parse("<?php echo $new_data; ?>");
        alert(data);
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode function in php